# Fetch -API returning HTML instead of JSON

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

I have a Spring REST API which I've tested on Postman and it returns perfectly valid JSON.
However when I call the same API on my front-end React Code it returns HTML.
This is the function, I'm using to call the API,

```
export function run(engine, mediaId, owner, target, access){
  let url = engine + "/" + mediaId + "?id=" + owner + "&targetId=" + target + "&access=" + access;

  return fetch(full_url, { credentials: "include",
                           headers: {
                             "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
                          }})
    .then((response) => {

      return response.json();})
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);

    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

I get a syntax error on this call `Unexpected token < Thus when I check using response.text()` I can see that the data returned is HTML and not JSON. What do I need to change in my front-end code for the API to return JSON.

Comment: please try "Content-Type" : "text/plain"

Comment: Did you got the answer?

Answer (score 27):

Header is not correct. Valid header for JSON response:

```
headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }
```

Comment: Nope still returning html

Comment: I am sorry. You modified your question later so I missed the term "Unexpected token".

Comment: Accept: application/json is key

Comment: For calling a FHIR server I also needed:
'Accept','application/json'

Answer (score 13):

Sometimes Apis return `html` instead of `json` if you are not logged in, confirm that as well

Comment: If that happens, what should we do ?

Comment: That was exactly my case

Comment: @FVBn then you should login, pass bearer token to api etc

Answer (score 1):

I am using my university network and using fetch function, but instead I'm receiving the HTML hardcoded text for the login page of the university network panel. I don't know why this is happening.
Solution: I grabbed the current URL from that HTML response and logged in into the network. Everything worked fine then.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Also double check you have selected the correct `HTTP` method in the dropdown box, next to the input bar on `postman`.